# Android: cannot install app saved to the internal memory

Tags: android, parsing, package

I am downloading an Android app from a server and saving it to the internal space of my application using:

```
URL url = new URL(Urls[0]);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
File outputFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "Apps");
outputFile.mkdirs();
File file = makeFilename(outputFile, _appName + ".apk");
file.createNewFile();
file.setExecutable(true);
file.setReadable(true, false);
file.setWritable(true, false);
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length = 0;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
fout.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
fout.close();
in.close();
outputFile.setExecutable(true, false);
outputFile.setReadable(true, false);
outputFile.setWritable(true, false);


private File makeFilename(File base, String name) {
        if (name.indexOf(File.separatorChar) < 0) {
            return new File(base, name);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File " + name
                + " contains a path separator");
    }
```

when the download is completed, a notification appears. When I click this notification, the app should be installed. But in reality, when I click the notification, an "Error parsing the package" appears. What I am doing wrong?

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir()+ "/Apps/_appName.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
PendingIntent act = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity._activity,0, i, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo("TEXT", "TEXT, act);
```

Comment: Can you include what is displayed in logcat?

Comment: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a doubt for your downloaded .apk file is **Private to your application** itself.

So just check it,

And also when you store file in your application make sure it has, **WORLD_READABLE** Permission like,

`Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE`

Something like,

```
OutputStream myOutputFile = openFileOutput("xxxx.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```